# Changing width of GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid-layout

I use the GridLayout for my JPanel and was wondering, if it's possible to change the width of the columns:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(5,2);
panel.setLayout(grid);
```

Is there a simple way?

Comment: do you want to have columns of different width?

Comment: I would consider both, different widths for the columns and altering the width of the whole layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use separate grid layout for each column.

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(1,2); 
    GridLayout grid1 = new GridLayout(5,1);
        GridLayout grid2 = new GridLayout(5,1);


        grid.add(grid1);
        grid.add(grid2);
```

You can now set widths of grid1 one  and grid2.

Comment: "grid" as a GridLayout object doesn't have "add". How should add them to themselves

Comment: Whatever this code example is supposed to do, it doesn't work as is. Are those layouts intended to be set to individual subpanels of a parent panel? Can you actually combine `GridLayout`s?

Answer (score 5):

Check the GridLayout api to see that the grid is made so all cells are the same size. If you want a component to be shown at it's preferred size, like (15,15), add it to a JPanel and add the JPanel to the GridLayout. The JPanel will expand to fill the gird cell and allow the component to be shown at it's preferred size.

For a row of different size you'll have to try something else. Nested layouts would be a good starting place...

You could always use the dreaded GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is close.  You need to add widgets to the Panel or Frame and not the Layout itself.  The Layout just tells the panels/frames how to organize the widgets added to it.

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
panel.add(<your panel widget>);
```